# HStack direction is incorrect for RTL Languages

Tags: swiftui

HStack has `layoutDirection` set to `.rightToLeft` show items aligned to the left side instead of the right.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    var data = ["Test  1", "Test 2"]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack{
                ForEach(data, id: \.self) { name in
                    Text(name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
            .environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I assume it should be handled automatically, did you try without `.environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)` (it can reverse RTL applied by system)?

Comment: @Asperi unfortunately, same issue

Comment: Would you provide standalone reproducible example?

Comment: @Asperi sure, I updated the example code and screenshot

Comment: I bet it is not a HStack, but ScrollView which is always LTR.

Comment: @Asperi you are right, if you removed the ScrollView wrapper, it will align items rightToLeft. So it's ScrollView issue

Comment: @Asperi I managed to fix the issue using flip and rotation content but I believe it's very bad solution https://gist.github.com/dotWasim/2462e32a29ec53b8ba4798f82cc206ee

Answer (score 0):

You can use the my below modifier.

https://gist.github.com/metin-atalay/bdf28a604fe9678403730d14f02946ca

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error or 'incorrect'. You should use a Spacer() in your HStack.

```
HStack{
    ForEach(data, id: \.self) { name in Text(name) }
    Spacer()
}
```